# How can I send a notification when the app closed on incoming call event?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, background-process

I'm trying to send a notification to phone, when incoming call is being received.It works already when my app is opened and when it's in the background. How can I send this notification (which has methods onNotificationPressed) when the app is closed?

It seems that
[local_notification_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) sends scheduled notifications.

[Alarm Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager/example) Doesn't have on incoming call method.(at least I couldn't find it)

Other simillar questions usually recommends these 2 plugins, but none of them seems to help.